# Format a number string into 2 decimal double independent of the number string length

Tags: android, kotlin, decimalformat, android-textwatcher, addtextchangedlistener

In Android application developed using Kotlin, there have an `EditText` which accepts number only which is considered as USD. The input needs to be formatted into 2 decimals so that the input needs to be formatted as below

- 7      ->   0.07
- 73     ->   0.73
- 736    ->   7.36

Tried using input filter. Input filter is also used to limit max value and single decimal input entry.

```
editTextField.filters =
            arrayOf(DecimalInputFilter())

class DecimalDigitsInputFilter() : InputFilter {
    override fun filter(
    source: CharSequence?,
    start: Int,
    end: Int,
    dest: Spanned?,
    dstart: Int,
    dend: Int
    ): CharSequence? {}

}
```

Couldn't manage to get the number formatted. Able to restrict inputs based on the rule.

```
editTextField.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
   override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        print("beforeTextChanged")
  }

  override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
       print("onTextChanged")
       val inputFormatter = DecimalFormat("0.00")
       inputFormatter.isDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown = true
       inputFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
       editTextField.setText((s.toString()).format(inputFormatter))
  }

  override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
       print("afterTextChanged")
  }
    
  })
```

This also fails.

Comment: Are `deliveryTipValue` and `editTextField` different?

Comment: Updated the question with correct name. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is that you are setting a text to the `EditText` inside of a `TextWatcher` which leads to looping recursion and then stack-overflow. You should change the text wrapped in removing and adding again the `TextWatcher`. Here is a simple solution:

```
editTextField.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        print("beforeTextChanged")
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        print("onTextChanged")

        val newValue = s.toString()
            .takeIf { it.isNotBlank() }
            ?.replace(".", "")
            ?.toDouble() ?: 0.0

        editTextField.let {
            it.removeTextChangedListener(this)
            it.setText(String.format("%.2f", newValue / 100))
            it.setSelection(it.text?.length ?: 0)
            it.addTextChangedListener(this)
        }
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        print("afterTextChanged")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Kotlin**

```
 fun roundOffDecimal(number: Double): String? {
        val df = DecimalFormat("#,###,###.##")
        df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING
        return df.format(number)
    }
```

RoundingMode.CEILNG or RoundingMode.FLOOR is used to round up the last digit.

```
#,###,###.##
```

customize this part according to the place value type you need and the number of decimal digits you want.

The above code will show the result something similar to **3,250,250.12**